# PHP - Check if an image loaded inside img src or directly inside browser?

Tags: php, giphy

Suppose i have an image url :- example.com/myimg.png

I want to check whether it is included inside img src or someone directly opened it via browser.

**What i need:-**
Check this image of GIPHY - https://media3.giphy.com/media/N8Lfh9gWcWYIU/giphy.gif

if you directly open it inside browser then it contains links at top and bottom of image but if you include this image inside img src then it only displays an image.

**I tried below code but it is not a reliable solution:-**

```
$ref = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']: "";
if ($ref != "")
{
    header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
    readfile( 'my-image.jpg' );
}
else
{
  <img src="my-image.jpg">
  <a href="#">My Link</a>
}
```

Comment: That's because the above giphy-link isn't actually a link to an image. It's a link to a page. The real image link for the above is https://i.giphy.com/media/N8Lfh9gWcWYIU/giphy.webp, which you can access directly.

Comment: Also, posting a link to an example doesn't really answer _"Why I need this"_. It's rather _"What I want"_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know that i.giphy.com/media/N8Lfh9gWcWYIU/giphy.webp is real image url but i can also pass https://media3.giphy.com/media/N8Lfh9gWcWYIU/giphy.gif inside img src attribute and it works without any issue - how it works if it is not an image?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you explain that further? When using `wget`, only the image is downloaded, no markup

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson is incorrect. The server *may* reply with an image or with a 302 redirect depending on `Accept` request header.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR giphy analyzes `Accept` HTTP header and also uses `Age:` header value greater than `Cache-Control: max-age=` value

When your browser loads an image in `<img>` tag, it sends specific `Accept` header. Firefox 71.0b12, for example, will use

```
Accept: image/webp,*/*
```

But if you open this URL in browser, even with same `Referer` header, the browser **will send another request** with header

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

But there is more. Due to caching browser will not send another request.

To avoid this, giphy will reply with following headers:

```
Last-Modified: ...
Etag: "..."
Content-Type: image/gif
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Age: 99360
```

*(other headers omitted, order not preserved)*

As you can see, **`Age` is greater than `max-age`**, so it is considered "stale" by the browser *instantly*, forcing another request when opening image directly.

*Note that this method may not work in all browsers.*